# Best library to convert React components to PNG/PDF?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-chartjs, react-pdf

I have implemented a react web app which creates charts using Chart.js library. Now I want to convert this charts to PNG/PDF formats and save them. I came across a lot of libraries but facing some or the other issue with them. Can you suggest which library would be perfect for this kind of work ?

App.js

```
class CreateChart extends Component {
// call to get chartData object
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              REACT CHARTS
            </header>
                <CreateChart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

Chart.js

```
class CreateChart extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
            this.myChart = new Chart(
                this.chartRef.current,
                this.props.chartData
            );
    }
    
    render() {
           return <canvas ref={this.chartRef} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Rendering arbitrary React components to PNG or PDF is an entirely different beast than rendering a Chart.js chart out. Have you googled "chart.js export png"?

Comment: Its API documentation consists of `.toBase64Image()` function. Not much information provided over this

Comment: There's not much documentation needed, since you get a standard data: URI out of that function.

Comment: @AKX exact, if you can get the base64 string, you can call jsPDF library next and add the image on a pdf document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to add an `id` on your html element (let's say `topdf`) :

```js
render() { return <canvas id="topdf" ref={this.chartRef} /> }}.
```

Then you can use the [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library to get the image dataURI of your charts.
After that, you can use the [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library to make a document and use the `.addImage(your_image_data_URI)` function.

Exemple :

```js
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#topdf"), { 
      scale: 3, // use the desired scale
      allowTaint: true,
      useCORS: true
    }).then(canvas => { 

      // Your IMAGE_DATA_URI
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

      // Make pdf
      var doc = new jsPDF({ options });

      // add image
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG');

      // Save document
      doc.save('charts.pdf'); 

      // ....
```

This only work onInit runtime, or after runtime.

Comment: I do not have a canvas id or something that sort of. In place of canvas id, how can I make use of react refs. I am using `this.chartRef.current` in place of canvas_id but it shows a `Cannot read property 'chartRef' of undefined` error.
You can find the code in the question section.

Comment: Why don't you add  : `render() { return <canvas id="an_id" ref={this.chartRef} /> }}` ?

Comment: You only can [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) a DOM element. And it's exactly what you want, get a charts made on runtime by React, then querySelector it on the generated DOM after runtime, and save it with an action/function/feature ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you tried to say, I am new to react. Can you please help me with what should be my first argument in `html2canvas()` or you are trying to suggest something else ?

Comment: I'm trying to suggest you to add and id (let's say `topdf` on your canvas `render() { return <canvas id="topdf" ref={this.chartRef} /> }}`. Now if you inspect your application on chrome for exemple (F12), you can select the canvas element and see it get the id. From this, you can make a function toPDF() and use html2canvas like this : `html2canvas(document.querySelector("#topdf"), { ....`

Comment: But as mentionned above, if your API had an `.toBase64Image()`, this function return a encoded base64 string (which contain the png/jpeg encoded) of the chart. With this base64 string, you don't need to use html2canvas. You can directly use jsPDF and use `.addImage(the base 64 string)`

Comment: Wow .. that was a really good explanation and it got me going. It works. Can you please modify your main answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: The html2canvas() worked for me but yes I also want to make use of the png file. 
I am getting the encoded string but for some reasons it is giving me a complete black screen when I tried opening that URI on chrome.

Comment: Also, the html2canvas() gives a graph based on the current browser resolution size. And it is not producing a clear pdf compared to the webpage. Is there any advance options where I can get the pdfs more clearer?

Comment: I'm updating the answer. :) Yes, you can play with the `scale` parameter of html2canvas. Then you can use `doc.viewerPreferences({'FitWindow': true}, true);` to fit your scaled image on your document. But this is more tricky! Now you have a base to get the image, and make a pdf. There is so much [parameters](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-addImage.html)

Comment: @AmitPathak i suggest you to lookup to this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/peqVOM). There is more detail about how to scale the image. (Just don't take the work before line 142, because it's all what html2canvas is doing)